# Printing content loaded from server

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, printing

I'm loading some picture from server by JS after whole page is loaded.
Means by user click i'm loading some image and insert it into DOM.

This image has unique ID, now i want to print out this image ONLY by JS help.
I did style  file for printing purpose

```
* {
    display:none;
    visibility: none;
}
html, body, #out_image_1 {
    background: none;
    display: block !important;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

and calling print such

```
$("#print-button2").click(function() {
    window.print();
    return false;
})
```

but page is blank (empty) Where i'm wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons it might not be printing.

- Your image may be contained in another element, but according to your CSS, the parent element is still `display:none`

  Your CSS will work only if `#out_image_1` is a direct child of `body`:
  http://jsfiddle.net/RXMx8/

  But not if `#out_image_1` has any parent elements other than `body` and `html`:
  http://jsfiddle.net/RXMx8/1/

I'm betting that's the issue, but other reasons could be:

- Your browser is not set to print images by default. Using `window.print()` may skip the "print preview" which could allow you to toggle this setting on.
- Your HTML is OK, but you're targeting the wrong element.
- You're out of ink ; )

Even though you're adding the element with javascript, you should still be able to print it. For debugging, remove the `* { display:none; }` and see what happens.

<sup>* By the way, it should be `visibility: hidden;`; "none" is not a valid value, but it's redundant with `display:none` anyways so you don't need it at all.</sup>

Comment: Yes and you are right. Is there any way how to solve it if my image not a direct child of body ?

Comment: You have to make sure all the parent elements are displayed. Without seeing your script or HTML, I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: can I move this img tag as a direct child of body for ptinting purpose and when printing is finished get it back on previous position ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, it might work but it might not. Give it a try. You might try to load a separate window with a print-only page, call `window.print()` then `window.close()`, but that's pretty hacky.

Comment: but what about hidden iframe ? is it possible to load image there by js, then call window.print and with help CSS set visible inly for this iframe with defined width and height?  what do you think ?

Comment: I wish I could tell you, printing is sometimes mysterious to me. However, that sounds like a pretty good idea. I'm sure there are loads of ways you can solve this but I still haven't seen your code.